# Features matching on multiple images

Tags: matlab, opencv, matching

I am trying to implement feature matching on multiple images. The idea is to track some features in an image data set. I am using mexopenCV on Matlab and the basics of the algorithm are:

```
1. Feature Detection using SIFT or SURF
2. Feature Description using SIFT or SURF
3. Feature matching using Flann matcher or Brute Force
4. Filtering matches using RANSAC
```

My problem is the following:
Using a single object in a scene, all of the tracked features are on that object. However, when I add another object to the scene, the tracked features are only existing on the new object and there are no features on the first object. Is there an explanation for why this is happening ?

**Image 1**

[image]

**Image 2**

[image]

P.S: The features on each image are the ones that are tracked on all the data set (8 images).

Comment: I have added the images for you so that you are more likely to get a reply.

Comment: This is super weird. In my experience you will just get more features, not just features in the new object. Do you have a upper cap in the amount of features your algorithm can detect?

Comment: Have you set a maximum number of features? If you posted some code that might help

Comment: I think it's related to how RANSAC behaves. The board and the statue in the scene don't have the same depth and what RANSAC do is that he's trying to find the best model with the most number of features to match. But given that there are two models (Because of the depth change in the scene), RANSAC will only match features in the best of the two. I searched more and found that it's related to multi-modal fitting. There's sequential RANSAC or multi RANSAC that handles this but I am still not sure of my conclusion. Does anyone can say that that's the reason ?

Comment: And no there is no maximum number of features that's set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I found the reason for finding features only on one object. As I mentioned in a comment, RANSAC will try to find the best model when matching the features. Since we have a change in depth for the two objects, we basically have two models to befitted. I searched for multi-modal fitting and found that there's [Sequential RANSAC](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~dfouhey/thesis/dfouhey_thesis.pdf) and [Multi-RANSAC](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~dfouhey/thesis/dfouhey_thesis.pdf) that solves this. I have tried with sequential RANSAC by setting the number of models to 2 and got a nice result.

[image]